# How do I avoid nil with a dynamic finder when an attribute comes as nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dynamic-finders

```
link_to 'articles', articles_path, :attr1 => 'foo', :attr2 => 'bar'
```

And in the controller:

```
Article.find_all_by_attr1_and_attr2(params[:attr1], params[:attr2])
```

However if  the controller receives only `[:attr1]` I get a nil.

Comment: What would you do in that case then? There's not enough information to answer this question effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic finders may not be the right way to go if some of finders aren't actually present. In this case, you're probably better off using `Article.find(:all, :conditions => {})` on Rails 2 and `Article.where()` on Rails 3.

Here's a method I came up with for another question a while back:

```
conditions = [:attr1, :attr2].inject({}) do |hsh, field|
  hsh[field] = params[field] if params[field] && params[field].present?
  hsh
end

# Rails 2
@articles = Article.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)

# Rails 3
@articles = Article.where(conditions)
```

In the above case, you'd loop over all fields in the array, and add each one of them to the resulting hash if it's in and not empty in `params`. Then, you pass the hash to the finder, and everything's fine and dandy.